# Putty with NAS4FREE - Directory "not found"

Tags: ssh, putty, path

Basically, the directory I want to access is listed but I can't access it.

Below is the Putty command line:-

```
login as: root
root@192.168.0.104's password:
Last login: Thu Sep 26 21:14:38 2013 from 192.168.0.102
Welcome to NAS4Free!
nas4free: ~ # cd /mnt/
Important Stuff/ Main Storage/    Main/
nas4free: ~ # cd /mnt/Important Stuff/
Stuff/ not found

nas4free: ~ # cd /mnt/Important Stuff/
nas4free: ~ #
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the space in the directory name:

```
cd /mnt/Important\ Stuff/
```